# Access SAP B1 Form settings programmatically?

Tags: c#, sapb1

In my SAP add-on there's a function which adds some changes to a "Sales Order" or a "Sales Quotation" form once the user click "ok" after adding items.

But my function only works if the `Discount%` field is activated in form settings. Otherwise the add-on crashes.

How can I check if the `Discount%` is activated in the form settings?

If I can check that, I can display a message asking the user to activate the field before using the function again.

The add-on is coded in C#

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted this question in SAP community network website and I got the answer from there. The same answer can be seen below.

```
kMatrix = SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Items.Item("38").Specific;
```

//the matrix was defined in my constructor.

```
if (kMatrix.Columns.Item("15").Editable == false)
{
  SBO_Application.MessageBox("Please activate the Discount% in form settings...", 1, "Ok");
}
```

//Here the value `"15"`is the column value for discount% in form "Sales Order". If you want to do the same check for a different column, replace `"15"`with your desired column value.